# Typo in Help Center: Serial Upvoting or Downvoting reversed

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center

[The page](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/serial-voting-reversed) says

> What if I think I'm the victim of voting fraud?
>
> If voting fraud is in the **progress** of happening or just happened recently to your account, don't worry about it. (emphasis added)

I think it should be process instead of progress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typo fixed - thanks for the report!